# Deploy on premise web app with transformed release configs

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, xdt-transform

We are in the process of setting up our release definitions to finally finish the last piece of our CD/CI setup in VSTS and are running into an issue where we are unable to transform our configs.

Currently we are following [Scott Hanselman's](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/BestPracticesForPrivateConfigDataAndConnectionStringsInConfigurationInASPNETAndAzure.aspx) approach of keeping connection strings and secrets out of our web.config via a secrets.config because we don't want any of that information committed to source control. If there is a better practice for this scenario we are open to switching but currently unsure of how this would integrate with VSTS CD/CI.

We've tried using the [XDT Transform Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.xdttransform#overview) to transform our web.base.config to web.config to remove the file and the configsource references but it doesn't seem to be transforming.

[image]

We've also used the IIS Web App Deploy task with the XML transformation and XML variable substitution but the transformation isn't working because the web.base.config doesn't exist in the artifacts. I'm not sure why that is not being pulled in on build.

[image]

We'd like to know what best practice is for any or all of these different steps and how we can accomplish an on premise deployment successfully without committing config settings to source control. We'd also like to know how to execute this methodology for console apps as well.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with DB connection strings appearing in your web.config, it's not as if it's visible externally.   If you are worried about passwords you may want to consider using say Windows authentication rather than SQL username/password.   The best security is when you don't mention a password at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the web.base.config file isn’t uploaded to source control and no in build agent machine, so you can’t use XDT Transform or XML transformation task/feature.

You can store the data in [secret variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/variables?tabs=batch#secret-variables) or Azure Key Vault and link it to release definition.

For example:

1. Add a new variable (click lock icon) or link Azure key Vault in release definition (e.g. connectionStrings)
2. Way 1: Check XML variable substitution option (Variables defined in the Build or Release Definition will be matched against the 'key' or 'name' entries in the appSettings, applicationSettings, and connectionStrings sections of any config file and parameters.xml. Variable Substitution is run after config transforms.), then the variable value will be replaced to the config files
3. Way 2: If the web app published as the web deployment package: override web deploy parameters (**SetParameters.xml** )by specifying value in Override Parameters input in release task. (You can add parameters.xml file to the project, then the related parameters will be added to SetParameters.xml file when generate web deployment package) [Configuring Parameters for Web Package Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/web-deployment-in-the-enterprise/configuring-parameters-for-web-package-deployment)
4. Way 3: Using [Replace Token task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) to replace the token in a file (e.g. `#{mypassword}#`) to the variable value (`mypassword`)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. Our web.base.config actually is in our source control which is why we tried to transform originally but for some reason it doesn't show up in our artifacts after build.

Comment: If web.base.config file isn't added to project, then it won't be added to build output. Since it contains secret information, you shouldn't add it to the source control or build artifacts.

Comment: Thank you! Way 2 works perfeclty with On Premise deployment from Azure Dev Ops.